# Converting curl to python for accessing an api

Tags: python, api, curl

I'm having trouble converting curl code to python in order to access a token to an API.

The given code is:

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=PRODUCTION" -H "Authorization :Basic <long base64 value>, Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://api-km.it.umich.edu/token
```

I know that -H indicates a header, however Im not sure what to do with -d.  So far I have:

```
authorizationcode = 'username:password'
authorizationcode = base64.standard_b64encode(authorizationcode)
header = {'Authorization ': 'Basic ' + authorizationcode, 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-' + authorizationcode}

r = requests.post('https://api-km.it.umich.edu/token',
    data = 'grant_type=client_credentials&scope=PRODUCTION',
    headers = header)
```

Also, these are the instructions:

Obtain your consumer key and consumer secret from the API Directory. These are generated on the Subscriptions page after an application is successfully subscribed an API.
Combine the consumer key and consumer secret keys in the format: consumer-key:consumer-secret.  Encode the combined string using base64. Most programming languages have a method to base64 encode a string. For an example of encoding to base64.  Visit the base64encode site for more information.
Execute a POST call to the token API to get an access token.

Our data is correct however we are getting a 415 error from the server.

Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: '-d' is the 'data' to be sent in the body of the request, and you seem to have applied that correctly in your post method call.  What is the trouble?

Comment: we're getting a 415 error from the server

Comment: you have added your `authorizationcode` to the end of the Content-Type header.  It should just be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` just like the curl request.

Comment: @krock if I get rid of the is the  authorization code supposed to follow basic or should it not be in my header at all?

Comment: the Content-Type header describes the format in the body of the request.  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is a standard form post.  Auth data doesn't go into the `Content-Type` header

Comment: Resolved. Deleting authorizationcode after content type was all we needed to do

Comment: We removed the credentials from the post; since they have been up for 3 whole weeks, you *really* should look into resetting those. They were working for me still.

Answer (score 0):

A 415 Error is described in http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E415.html as "Unsupported media type"

As @krock mentioned, the content-type is not specified as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, rather it is being set to `x-www-form-` + your auth code.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting an incorrect `Content-Type` header:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-' + authorizationcode
```

That should be `'application/x-www-form-urlencode'`. You do not, however, have to set it *at all* as `requests` does this for you automatically if you pass in a dictionary to the `data` argument.

`requests` will also handle the `Authorization` header for you; pass in the username and password to the `auth` argument as a tuple:

```
auth = ('username', 'password')
params = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 'scope': 'PRODUCTION'}

r = requests.post('https://api-km.it.umich.edu/token', data=params, auth=auth)
```

where `user` and `password` are the parts before and after the colon. `requests` will produce the correct *Basic* base64-encoded header for you from those two strings.